# How does a later update affect scaffolded files?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I refer to this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

I had `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` 3.1.1 when I scaffolded it to get the source of the Razor Pages. I have made changes to some of the Razor Pages.

The package is now on 3.1.4. Can I update the package? If I do so will it overwrite my changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the identity nuget will not overwright any of your changes, but scaffolding it again will ask a confirmation to overwite the existing files.

Comment: After updating, which version will be running?  The updated version or my modified version?

Comment: The scaffolded (modified) version will run, till you scaffold the newer version and overwrite the existing files.